# P2G Alignment Algorithm in Python (OS X)

Tags: computational-linguistics, phonemes, python

I'm looking for a basic phoneme-grapheme alignment algorithm which can be called in Python from a machine running OS X. So far the only implementations I've been able to find are part of larger C++ libraries ([here](https://github.com/AdolfVonKleist/Phonetisaurus) and [here](https://github.com/letter-to-phoneme/m2m-aligner)) which seem like they would be overkill to install, especially given the added difficulty of getting them running on an OS X machine.

Does anyone know of a good standalone P2G implementation written in Python?
 Maybe something living in a git gist somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured I'd post an answer in case it helped anyone else in the future. I wound up installing [Jiampojamarn's m2m-aligner](https://github.com/letter-to-phoneme/m2m-aligner), callable via the terminal, and it works great. I used this to preprocess all of grapheme/phoneme pairs in the CMU Pronunciation Dictionary prior to runtime, and saved the results in a custom `GraphemePhonemeAlignment` Python class.

One trick for anyone trying to get the m2m-aligner working on OSX: I had to delete the `lgcc_s` requirement from the makefile in order to get the `make` command to work. After that, the program ran like a charm.

Comment: I ended up writing my own aligner in Python and it picked up inconsistencies in the CMU dictionary. Message me if anyone wants